# Business Catalyst - Form is emailing wrong person

Tags: forms, web-applications, adobe, business-catalyst

I hope this will make sense. I've built a classified website. A customer can post an item for sell. At the bottom of the item details page is a form. This form is used by other users who'd like to get a hold of the owner.

I made the mistake of copying live source code into my web app. Therefore, the emails all go to me, not the owner of the item.

Can anyone decipher the tag that needs to be put in place so the emails go to the owner of the product?

Sample URL
http://www.wrenchbox.com/cars-for-sale/1970-chevrolet-chevelle

```
<form action="/Default.aspx?A=Form&amp;Email=**TAGGOESHERE**&amp;Subject=Sell+Your+Car+Enquiry&amp;EmailFrom=&amp;PageID=/contact-thank-you.html" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkWholeForm4616(this)" method="post" name="catwebformform4616">
```

Answer (score 1):

In Business Catalyst form submissions go to all admins by default, so you can do two things:

1. Assign the form a workflow then add a step to the workflow to email the person.
2. Make the person an admin and they will receive form submissions. You can also tell them that all form submissions are stored in the CRM as a case.